# usage of any+single in “Sorry, for some reason I can't remember any fairy tale now.”

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Consider the sentence:

> “Sorry, for some reason I can't remember any fairy tale now.”

I'm not sure is this correct or no, but for me it sounds much better if we change "fairy tale" to plural. So main question is what would be more correct, with "fairy tale" in plural or singular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say:

> I can't remember any **fairy tales** at the moment.

But the singular says you are trying to think of exactly one tale, but you can't think of *any*.

The use of *any* with a singular noun is fine.  It's a kind of shortened way of saying "any of the many X that there are".  Other examples:

> A: Which apple do you want?
>   B:  Just give me **any apple**.  They're all the same.
>
> I'll take **any job** that you have.  I need the work.
>
> I can't think of **any person** who is qualified to do the job.